# GraphQL mutation query max length for text field

Tags: graphql, text

I'm trying to insert a quite long text via GraphQL into a text field. I get the following error message when doing so:

> 'Bio Helper should contain at most 65,535 characters.'

When I copy and paste the whole text in the field via the CP, it works. So it seems like the limit comes from the `String` type not the field I'm trying to populate. [String shouldn't have a limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57552296/size-limit-for-graphql-scalar-string), so I'm wondering where it comes from (and how to increase it).

This is my query:

```
mutation saveEntry(
    $siteId: Int
    $authorId: ID
    $title: String
    $info: String
    $bioHelper: String
) {
    save_artist_default_Entry(
        siteId: $siteId
        authorId: $authorId
        title: $title
        info: $info
        bioHelper: $bioHelper
    ) {
        id
    }
}
```